# How to add a property of custom date time user control that set datetime value and get string value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a custom `datetime` `UserControl` that need a property named `SelectedDate` which will `set` `datetime` value and get string value on textbox.

```
private DateTime objDate;
public DateTime SelectedDate {
  get {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text))
      return objDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    else
      return DateFormat.DateStringDisplay(txtDate.Text).ToString();
  }

  set {
    objDate = value;
    if (value != null) {
      this.objDate = DateFormat.ConvertStringToDate(txtDate.Text);
    }
  }
}
```

but can't solve my problem.Anyone there to help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: My UserControl.ascx page code:                                                        
 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate"  runat="server" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImgCalender" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" Height="17px" OnClick="imgCalender_Click" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender  ID="dateCalenderExt"  runat="server"
        PopupButtonID="btnImgCalender"
        CssClass="AjaxCalendar"
        PopupPosition="BottomLeft"
        TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />

Comment: It is unclear to me what your problem is. I see your code, but You need to also sat what your problem is

Comment: `SelectedDate` is a `DateTime` object. You can't return a `string` object because that's not what it's defined as. You'd have to make another property like `SelectedDateAsString` which would simply `return SelectedDate.ToString();` (or format it however first) but then the question is why don't you just return the `DateTime` object and let the calling class decide if it should be a `string` or keep it as a `DateTime`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.Actually I need the SelectedDate property for custom  dateControl that simply set DateTime value and get String value to show the textbox. Is there any suggestions?